# How do I to add css bootstrap at a c# class?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to return a html string which I'll send email, it works well but I want to add bootstrap style and I cannot do this. How do I to do this ?

**Trying**

```
public static String getHtmlMessage(long numero, string descricao, decimal valor){

        string absolute_url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
        string html = "";
        html += "<html>";
        html += "<head>"; 

        html += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css \" type=\"text/css\" >";

        html += "</head>";
        html += "<body>";
        html += "<img src=" + "https://" + absolute_url + "/Imagens/logo2.png" + " width=\"250\" />";
        html += "<h3>Message </h3>";
        html += "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
        html +=     "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + "<strong>Data:</strong> " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss") + "</li>";
        html +=     "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + "<strong>Nº.Sorte:</strong> " + String.Format("{0:000000}", numero) + "</li>";
        html +=     "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + "<strong>Descrição:</strong> " + descricao + "</li>";
        html +=     "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + "<strong>Valor(R$):</strong> " + String.Format("{0:N}", valor) + "</li>";
        html +=     "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + "<strong>Total(R$):</strong> " + String.Format("{0:N}", valor) + "</li>";
        html += "</ul>";
        html += "<h5>Footer message</h5>";        
        html += "</body></html>";

        return html;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through this pain before, the short answer is you can't. From an article on css tricks

***Things you can't do:*** ... Link to an external stylesheet. Not many email clients support this, best to just forget it."

Full article: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

There's a lot of other styling problems that come up in terms of layout and sizing. It definitely isn't as simple as I figured it should have been